# Having all one single line with black background and text in white

Tags: formatting, color

I want to have one line of text with black background and the text in white. The line is alone and so it can be one paragraph.

I would like the coloration for the full width of the line and not only for the text.

The solution must work inside one minipage.

Comment: Is the line going to be a separate paragraph, or do you want to colour a single line in a larger paragraph?

Comment: Indeed, the line will be alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\newcommand*\mylineI[1]{%
\par\noindent
\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax][l]{\strut\color{white}#1}}%
\par}

\newcommand*\mylineII[1]{%
  \par\noindent\adjustbox{bgcolor=black,innercode={\color{white}}{},}%
                     {\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\strut #1}}%
  \par%
}
\begin{document}
\mylineI{Text Text Text Text}

\mylineII{Text Text Text Text}

\end{document}
\myline{Text Text Text Text}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: The second command uses the package `adjustbox`. So you have some extra options.

Of course the code can be extended width extra spacing and `\xspace`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this coloration is only for the text and not for the whole line... I've updated my question.

Comment: @projetmbc: I edited my answer and now using `makebox`.

Comment: Is there a way to minimize the spacing before the text ?

Comment: @projetmbc: Do you mean the space inside the black line? I used `\par` to create a new line. You can manipulate this.

Comment: Your second command looks better for my purpose. That's great !

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\colorbox{black}{%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
\strut\color{white}hello
\end{minipage}%
}
```

[image]

A new environment to do the equivalent is

```
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\makeatletter\newenvironment{blackbox}
    {\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}\strut\color{white}}
    {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\colorbox{black}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}}
\makeatother
```

which will give the same result with

```
\begin{blackbox}
hello
\end{blackbox}
```

Note that this leads to an overfull box if unless `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}` is used before it. With that, the output looks like

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to indicate that I'll use this formatting in one minipage...

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: You forgot some `%` and width `\textwidth` you created an overfull box. You must substrate the `\fboxsep` of `\colorbox`.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Please see my answer (\dimexpr). Your second code uses a savebox. So you allows breaks.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Why sorry.? You provided an alternative and tex stackexchange is a collection of solutions ;-)

Comment: I'll leave it in that case, with a disclaimer that it leads to an overfull box. :)

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I edited you answer. Now you have no overfull boxes.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks for the edit. I understand now. That's a neat way of reducing the box size to fit!