# How to print in white text over black background

Tags: fonts, color, printing

I already have set a document with text and image. On the whole document:

## Is it possible to make the white background go set to black?

#### That is: text in white color & background in black color.

I know this is very anti-economical print-wise, but it's for artistic purposes. In this approach I would only be printing the black sections in a regular printer.

There's also a black and white image, and gray too (cc symbol). If I can keep that in original colors it'd be best. (Or not! ..oh my! I have to check how it looks)

This has been done before but not on such a big scale of page:

- [for just a couple of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/verbatim-with-black-background-and-white-text)
- [same idea but with (undesirable) white space between lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37559/having-all-one-single-line-with-black-background-and-text-in-white)
- [for tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51858/white-text-on-black-background-in-entire-table)
- [on titles/sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58855/format-section-titles-as-white-text-on-black-background)
- [for a bit in article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148807/white-colored-text-and-black-background-using-the-article-class)

## Perhaps an option to invert colors in full document?

This would change the image. But since it's only one maybe that can be inverted too.

---

Another chance could be to just take the .tex file and format the color of text (and leaving background unchanged): change black (standar) color of letters to white and get a proper printer and use black paper as background. It'd be great to hear ideas on this option too. Although printing with white ink on black-tainted pages may be even more expensive than the 1st option...

---

SeRe's answer is just great. I'm just going to add a `mwe` of my own because I had some frames that went back to default and I wanted to post how I managed to customize them to be as the rest of the document. Any other ideas on how to do this are more than welcome.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{mdframed}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black,linecolor=white,fontcolor=white]
\texttt{\textbf{Yes! Customized.}} \\
In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse
is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two
legs.\end{mdframed}

\mdfapptodefinestyle{example1}{backgroundcolor=brown!20,linecolor=red!40!black,linewidth=4pt}
\begin{mdframed}[style=mdfexample1]\textit{No: Default mdframed.} \\Not desirable white backgroundcolor and text in black.\end{mdframed}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284327/reverse-white-and-black-colors-in-a-pdf

Comment: @HenriMenke How do you use Ghostscript, through terminal? It's several lines long

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
 \documentclass[a4, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

This gives you as global pagecolor black and as global textcolor white. I think that this is what you're looking for. For further information, you can also have a look on the [pagecolor package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor?lang=de)

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume you have the following 259 page document, littered with text and images:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\newcounter{lipsumcntr}

\begin{document}

\loop\unless\ifnum\value{lipsumcntr}=50
  \stepcounter{lipsumcntr}
  \lipsum[1-\thelipsumcntr] {\centering \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}\par}
\repeat

\end{document}
```

It is not possible to retro-actively change a PDF from within (La)TeX. It is a processed, binary format. (La)TeX can only display it as-is without much change. As such, you might be encouraged to follow a conversion process that I list below. Everything can be done in bulk.

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Burst the PDF into single-page PDFs using [The PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/):

   ```
   pdftk myfile.pdf burst
   ```

   This creates a bunch of `pg_XXXX.pdf` files, one for each page where `XXXX` has a leading `0`. The above document therefore produces the files `pg_0001.pdf` through `pg_0259.pdf`.
2. Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to bulk-`convert` and [`-negate`](https://askubuntu.com/a/541897/5764) each page:

   ```
   mogrify -format png -negate -sharpen 0x0.1 -density 300 -quality 100 pg_0*.pdf
   ```

   I've tried to keep a [high-quality output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605006/914686).
   Depending on the image quality chosen to convert the burst pages to PNG, this may take quite a while.
3. Create a new PDF containing the `-negate`d images:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,pagecolor}
   \newcounter{pgcntr}
   \pagecolor{black}% Black page background

   \begin{document}

   \pagestyle{empty}% No page header/footer

   \loop\unless\ifnum\value{pgcntr}=259
     \clearpage
     \mbox{}% Just put something on the page
     \stepcounter{pgcntr}
     \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
       \AtPageLowerLeft{
         \edef\pgnum{\ifnum\value{pgcntr}<100 0\fi\ifnum\value{pgcntr}<10 0\fi\thepgcntr}% Prepend with 0s
         \includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{pg_0\pgnum.png}% Insert image
       }
     }
   \repeat

   \end{document}
   ```

   The above loop inserts an `\mbox{}` on every *blank* page (no header/footer) and places a subsequent page - a PNG file - in the `F`ore`G`round so that it fits exactly within the page geometry (with the aid of [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)).

   We create a `\pgnum` macro to hold the page number about to be included. This macros prepends the actual page number with sufficient `0`s in order to retrieve the required filename.

   Depending on the image quality chosen to convert the burst pages to PNG, this may take quite a while.
4. Clean-up:

   ```
   del pg_0*.pdf
   del pg_0*.png
   ```
5. Print