# Change background colour to black and text to white?

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, presentations

I am using the following code for a beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\title[short version]{SOME TITLE}
%\subtitle[short version]{}
%\date{}
\author[SOME AUTHOR]{SOME AUTHOR}
\institute[SOME INSTITUTE]{SOME INSTITUE}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[t]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get a black background colour and white text. How do I get that effect?

Thanks

Comment: See [How to print in white text over black background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320605/5764).

Comment: Since you're using [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer), you may have to change the template colours or theme. See [`beamer` theme matrix](//hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)...

Answer (score 9):

Another approach could be to simply choose one of the dark colour themes

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\title[short version]{SOME TITLE}
%\subtitle[short version]{}
%\date{}
\author[SOME AUTHOR]{SOME AUTHOR}
\institute[SOME INSTITUTE]{SOME INSTITUE}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}

\usecolortheme{owl}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[t]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove [brazil] if you do not have that on your system.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the best option out there for presentations (black, quirky CM Sans...), but here you go:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\title[short version]{SOME TITLE}
%\subtitle[short version]{}
%\date{}
\author[SOME AUTHOR]{SOME AUTHOR}
\institute[SOME INSTITUTE]{SOME INSTITUE}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}


%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{itemize}
    \item blá blá 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item blá blá 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```